# How to update Previous and Next links after deletion of the rows in Angular Table?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement to delete row elements on checkBox enable on the row elements and click of `Delete` button.
On Clicking the Delete the button, I'm able to delete the Items in the table.But unable to update the Prev and Next links appropriately as per the page numbers.

```
Scenario:
Row Id    Row Value

1           Row1
2           Row2
3           Row3

Showing 1-3 of 9 Next //Since it is in Page Number 1

Row Id    Row Value

4           Row4
5           Row5
6           Row6

Showing 4-6 of 9 Prev Next // Since it is in Page Number 2

Row Id    Row Value

7          Row7
8          Row8
9          Row9

Showing 7-9 of 9 Prev  // Since it is in the last page, Nex link is disabled.

I'm trying to a achieve a scenario like if user selects the 7,8,9 and delete them, then 
It should display

Row Id    Row Value

4           Row4
5           Row5
6           Row6

Showing 4-6 of 6 Prev
```

Html

```
<button type = "button" (click)="deleteSelectedItems()">Delete Items</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Row Id</th>
        <th>Row Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let row of paginatedMessages; let i = index;">
            <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)] = "row.isSelected" (change) = "onCheck($event, row.id, i)" /></td>
            <td>{{row?.id}}</td>
            <td>{{row?.rowValue}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<span> 
    {{paginatedString}}
    <a class = "link" (click) = "showPrevItems()" *ngIf = "showPreviousBtn">Prev</a>
    <a class = "link" (click) = "showNextItems()" *ngIf = "showNextBtn">Next</a>
</span>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination-example',
  templateUrl: './pagination-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination-example.component.scss']
})
export class PaginationExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  showPreviousBtn : boolean = false;
  showNextBtn: boolean = false;
  paginatedMessages: any [] = [];
  allMessages: any [] = [];
  noOfMsgsPerPage = 5;
  pageNumber = 1;
  totalMessageCount: number = 0;
  paginatedString: string = '';
  checkBoxes: any[] = [];
  deletedMessageIds: any[] = []

  tableRows = [
    { id : "1", rowValue : "Row 1", isSelected : false },
    { id : "2", rowValue : "Row 2", isSelected : false},
    { id : "3", rowValue : "Row 3", isSelected : false},
    { id : "4", rowValue : "Row 4", isSelected : false},
    { id : "5", rowValue : "Row 5", isSelected : false},
    { id : "6", rowValue : "Row 6", isSelected : false},
    { id : "7", rowValue : "Row 7", isSelected : false},
    { id : "8", rowValue : "Row 8", isSelected : false},
    { id : "9", rowValue : "Row 9", isSelected : false},
    { id : "10", rowValue : "Row 10", isSelected : false},
    { id : "11", rowValue : "Row 11", isSelected : false},
    { id : "12", rowValue : "Row 12", isSelected : false},
    { id : "13", rowValue : "Row 13", isSelected : false},
    { id : "14", rowValue : "Row 14", isSelected : false},
    { id : "15", rowValue : "Row 15", isSelected : false},
    { id : "16", rowValue : "Row 16", isSelected : false},
    { id : "17", rowValue : "Row 17", isSelected : false},
    { id : "18", rowValue : "Row 18", isSelected : false},
    { id : "19", rowValue : "Row 19", isSelected : false},
    { id : "20", rowValue : "Row 20", isSelected : false},
]



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessagesData()
  }

  getMessagesData() {
    this.allMessages = [...this.tableRows];
    this.paginatedMessages = [...this.allMessages.slice(0, this.noOfMsgsPerPage)]
    this.totalMessageCount = this.allMessages.length;
    this.loadMessages();
    this.showPreviousBtn = false;
    this.showNextBtn = true;
    this.checkBoxes = new Array(this.allMessages.length);
    this.checkBoxes.fill(false)
  }

  loadMessages() {
    let start = (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.noOfMsgsPerPage + 1;
    let end = Math.min(start + this.noOfMsgsPerPage - 1, this.totalMessageCount) 
    this.paginatedMessages = this.allMessages.slice(start - 1, end);
    this.paginatedString = `Showing ${start} - ${end} of ${this.totalMessageCount}`
  }

  showNextItems() {
    this.paginatedMessages = [];
    this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
    this.showPreviousBtn = true;
    if(this.pageNumber == this.calculatePagesCount(this.noOfMsgsPerPage, this.totalMessageCount)) {
      this.showNextBtn = false;
    }
    this.loadMessages();
  }
  
  calculatePagesCount = (pageSize: any, totalCount: any) => {
    return totalCount < pageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(totalCount / pageSize);
  };

  showPrevItems() {
    this.paginatedMessages = [];
    this.showNextBtn = true;
    this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber - 1;
    if(this.pageNumber <= 1) {
      this.showPreviousBtn = false;
    }

    this.loadMessages();
  }

  onCheck(event:any, row: any , i:any) {
    console.log("Event :"+event+"i :"+i+ "Row :"+row);
    this.checkBoxes[i] = event.target.checked;
  }

  deleteSelectedItems() {
    this.deletedMessageIds = [];
    for (let i = this.checkBoxes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      // If selected, then delete that row.
      if (this.checkBoxes[i]) {
       let arr = this.paginatedMessages.splice(i, 1);
       arr.forEach(i => {
        this.deletedMessageIds.push(i.id)
       })
       console.log("Deleted Message Ids", this.deletedMessageIds)
      }
    }

    this.deletedMessageIds.forEach(item => {
      let index = this.allMessages.findIndex(x => x.id === item);
      if(index !== -1) {
        this.allMessages.splice(index, 1);
      }
    })
    this.totalMessageCount = this.allMessages.length;
    console.log("All Message", this.allMessages);

    let start = (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.noOfMsgsPerPage + 1;
    let end = Math.min(start + this.noOfMsgsPerPage - 1, this.totalMessageCount);

    this.paginatedMessages = this.allMessages.slice(start - 1, end);
    this.paginatedString = `Showing ${start} - ${end} of ${this.totalMessageCount}`
    
  }
}
```

This here is, when I delete the elements in the last page, `start` and `end` is not update appropriately

Result:

```
Row Id  Row Value


Showing 16 - 15 of 15 Prev
```

Can anyone please help in updating the Prev and Next (enable and disable) if I delete the items?

Adding the Demo
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grpr2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the booleans for the buttons.

**Instead do:**

```
<a class="link" (click)="showPrevItems()" *ngIf="paginatedMessages[0] !== allMessages[0]">Prev</a>
<a class="link" (click)="showNextItems()" *ngIf="paginatedMessages[paginatedMessages.length - 1] !== allMessages[allMessages.length - 1]">Next</a>
```

**And add a handle for the last page case:**

```
if (
      this.pageNumber >
      Math.ceil(this.allMessages.length / this.noOfMsgsPerPage)
    ) {
      this.pageNumber--;
    }
```

**Updated stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hervkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Note: The stackblitz also removed the buggy checkbox array handling. It now filters the array by the isSelected property

Comment: Losing track of the items when I delete one or more items in the 2 page . Could please modify it if possible

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Step1: Delete all the elements from last page, it moves to previous page with Next Button disabled. Step2: Delete 1 element from page 2. And Now delete 1 element from Page 1. Now getting weird result and unable to navigate to next elements

Comment: That is connected to your already existing bug with the redundant checkbox array. Remove that array too --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hervkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can achieve simelar results in your version when you delete the first item and click repeately delete. It will continue to delete the first without you having selected anything

Comment: Can you please modify the code to see correct results if possible..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247749/discussion-between-vijay-and-moxximanagarm).